# Double foreach break with a "If" statement?

Tags: c#, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Breaking out of a nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324831/breaking-out-of-a-nested-loop)

I got somthing like (to simplify)

```
foreach (...)
{
    foreach (...)
    {
        //Some code

        if (statement)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that I want my statement to leave for the double-foreach loop !
I'm thinking about a sort of "break flag" as a boolean but is there any way to avoid that ?

Comment: You can avoid it by using `Linq` and `SelectMany` to make this a single for-each loop instead of a nested loop.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham : dont know anything about it, giving a look at it !

Comment: @relaxxx : feels like I'll gotta use a breakflag as I was thinking so :(

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne why is useage of a breakflag so much unwanted for you? It is common solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could avoid the nested loop entirely by using Linq and `SelectMany`.

Instead of:

```
foreach(var value in someValues)
{
    foreach(var subValue in value.SubValues)
    {
        // ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Your code would become:

```
foreach(var subValue in someValues.SelectMany(v => v.SubValues))
{
    // ...
    break;
}
```

If you need some logic to select whether or not you loop over `SubValues`, throw that logic in an additional `Where` clause.

Instead of

```
foreach(var value in someValues)
{
    if(value.IsMumsHairGreenToday)
    {
        foreach(var subValue in value.SubValues)
        {
            // ...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You can write:

```
var subValues = someValues
    .Where(v => v.IsMumsHairGreenToday)
    .SelectMany(v => v.SubValues)
    ;

foreach(var subValue in subValues)
{
    // ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: Im not confortable with lambda expressions so didnt think about doing this, sounds nice as I avoid the breakflag and use a GOTO !

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne: You will never get comfortable until you use them all the time.  BTW: Please, don't ever use `goto`.  I don't care what the crowd says.  It is just sinful :)

Answer (score 13):

You may use [goto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Without using a break flag, goto is pretty much the only option to jump out of multiple nested loops.

Comment: @sll: Why? goto is a lot clearer than a flag in this case. KISS

Comment: Interesting - just mentioning `goto` causes immediate automatic downvotes ;) However weird it may sound, but exiting outer loops is done cleaner with `goto` than without it, so that's one scenario where using it is indeed justifyable. +1

Comment: I don't like 'int' going to use for everything 'double' instead ;)

Comment: I don't like `goto`, but this could be the only case in which it's to be used! Upvoted!

Comment: @jgauffin : I remembered rule `DO NOT USE goto for flow control` from university time studying Borland Pascal on the first course, I feel this rule makes sense and I treat goto as bad practice

Comment: @sll - sorry that's not a justification it's an excuse for not having your own point of view.  Did I mention I believe the world is flat because somebody told me it is?

Comment: @AndrasZoltan Very frequently on this site answers are downvoted because of a perception of best practice.  This is no different and is the reason I also downvoted.

Comment: @Andras Zoltan: Since we all born without any specific knowledges we are learn it from somewhere like development in university as a case, so this is original source where from knowledges may come into our minds and build/form our vision. So this is MY OWN point of view for this case. Even so I just suggesting not using it but understand another's point of view so I'm not downvoting such answers even I do not like it becuase it solves problem represented by the question

Comment: It's called a holy war for a reason.  OP: Don't use `goto`, and you'll make a lot of people happy.  The ones who think you should use it won't notice that it is missing :)

Comment: @sll: Yes. We have all learnt that. But it's not for cases like this, but for languages like BASIC where it were frequently used (or misused). The term Spaghetti code was coined by the misuse of GOTO. imho the advice against GOTO is no longer valid for modern languages as we don't use GOTO that much anymore.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan: It's not really important if it's his personal view or not. It's a fact that most programmers have been brain washed to hate GOTO. And it ***WAS*** for a good reason.

Comment: @jgauffin - absolutely I do agree with that and do, I guess, shy away from goto because of that same latent hatred (after all I didn't think of that as an answer!); I think your most recent comment to @sll sums that up, though, it's not as relevant with today's languages given the wealth of flow-control statements we have. Explaining why loads of `goto`s is bad is easy - one or two here or there in the absence of something better, though, is much harder, so probably doesn't warrant that prejudice.

Answer (score 9):

You could try:

```
bool leave = false;
foreach (...)
{
    foreach (...)
    {
        //Some code

        if (statement)
        {
            leave = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (leave) break;
}
```

edit: moved the break flag

Comment: yep that's the "breakflag" I was talking about but dont like it -_-

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne: ops, I didn't read about it...

Answer (score 6):

Sure, you should check [goto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/13940fs2.aspx).

Comment: Can any downvoter please elaborate why you did that?

Comment: Who and why did downvote that? Just because its common "logic" that goto is evil? No! Its not! It is still in the  language for a reason and it sometimes, while rare i agree, it is useful.

Comment: don't agree with the -2 here - he has a valid point :)

Answer (score 2):

As `break` only breaks out of the current loop you are going to have to test the break condition in the outer loop as well - unless you use a `goto` statement.

A variable would seem the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Imo one of the few cases where a careful [goto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx) is fine.

Answer (score 1):

you could encapsulate that logic in a method and return at the break point:

```
private SomeType CheckIfConditionOfNestedItems(IEnumerable enumerable)
{
    foreach (var thing in enumerable )
    {
        foreach (...)
        {
            //Some code

            if (statement)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

obviously this might need you to change your code a little, but this also has the advantage that it probably makes the code where you have the double loop much more readable.

Comment: doesnt fit well with my code -_-