# How can I use LINQ to avoid nested loops?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I've been reading about LINQ to Objects, and now my colleagues want me to present it to them.

Now, I have an OK understanding of the operators and the syntax choices, but I've heard you can **avoid heavy nested loops** by using LINQ. I'm having trouble coming up with a good set of "before and after" code listings to demonstrate this though.

I found a great example of sorting and grouping with and without LINQ in Magennis' book, and he also has an example of writing xml. But what about those nested loops? Is this even a realistic claim, given that we usually need a `foreach` loop or two to iterate over the results of the query anyway?

If anyone can explain this idea to me (ideally with specific examples), I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why the vote to close as "not constructive"?  Seems like the question could have broad usefulness and allows for one or more concrete answers.

Comment: @Henk: He's asking for concrete examples.  Perhaps the title could be improved to reflect that.

Comment: @Skywise Linq is very similar to SQL, you use joins to avoid nested loops.

Comment: It seems like this question could easily draw the kind of answers that will improve the average developer's understanding of how LINQ can be put to good use. I say: Give it a try. We can still close it after a day or so.

Comment: I miss django query api behavior on LINQ. Some thing like `invoices.objecs.filter( client__country__in = ['spain','france'] )`. Instead of this I should to write multiple joins or lots of nested loops. Someone else has a suggestion?

Comment: @danihp, what does your example do?  It doesn't look like anything that would be tough to do in LINQ)

Comment: @danihp, like `invoices.objects.Where(i=> (new string[]{"spain", "france").Contains(i.client.country)}`?

Comment: I agree, I see value in this question and would vote to re-open it.

Comment: @EricJ, yas4891, I disagree. SO is about "here is my problem, what is the solution." We can then identify the single best solution among arbitrarily many. This question is "create an arbitrary problem and then a solution where Linq is useful." This is not an effective SO question. We provide solutions to problems, not ideas for problems that then need a solution. This is a poll, not a question with a single best answer.

Comment: @Skywise: posted an example I use in some of my talks about the power of LINQ.  Easy example of a complex double-loop w dictionaries of lists reduced to a LINQ expression.

Comment: @Anthony: His wording is a little loose, but at the core he's asking "how can I use Linq to avoid heavily nested loops."  Seems specific enough to allow for specific, useful answers... which he got.

Comment: @Henk: Another user deleted your answer to this question, which I thought was a useful one.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram While I see your point (and it is certainly a good one), I beg to disagree on closing this type of question. From taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=votes&pagesize=50 I think that this type of question is really appreciated

Comment: @yas4891, and to that, I would say that note that many of those highly rated questions are from the infancy of StackOverflow, before the earth had cooled, so to speak, into the new normalcy. Notice that many of those questions are now closed, locked, specially marked as "not indicative of questions we currently accept," or a combination of all three. Indeed, there's even questions on Meta that are strictly there to keep track of [popular *deleted* questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-questions-list) (10K users can still see them).

Comment: At any rate, this has sparked a question on meta, so feel free to [provide your own opinion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113930/is-a-question-asking-for-examples-acceptable).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for good examples, and for keeping my question and improving my English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Say you've got a lot of products, such as:

```
var products = new List<Product>
    {
        new Product { Id = 1, Category = "Electronics", Value = 15.0 },
        // etc.
    };
```

And you want to find all products with a value > $100.0, grouped by category, you could do this using `foreach`:

```
var results = new Dictionary<string, List<Product>>();

foreach (var p in products)
{
    if (p.value > 100.0)
    {
        List<Product> productsByGroup;

        if (!results.TryGetValue(p.Category, out productsByGroup))
        {
            productsByGroup = new List<Product>();
            results.Add(p.Category, productsByGroup);
        }
        productsByGroup.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Or, you could simply use the LINQ methods:

```
var results = products.Where(prod => prod.Value > 100.0)
                  .GroupBy(prod => prod.Category);
```

Or using LINQ expression syntax:

```
var results = from p in products 
                  where p.Value > 100.0
                  group p by p.Category;
```

Much more concise and less error-prone.

Comment: Thanks, James. I set your as my accepted answer, as I think it looks very realistic and it is spot on what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a type of nested loop you can remove with Linq.

```
foreach(SomeClass item in Items)
{
    foreach(SomeOtherClass subItem in item.SubItems)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It can be turned into:

```
foreach(SomeOtherClass subItem in Items.SelectMany(i => i.SubItems))
{
}
```

Using [the `SelectMany` extension method on `IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx).

One place where this is quite useful is for [nested loop double-break scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8150642/232593).

Answer (score 2):

```
var results = new List<Object>();
foreach(var i in list)
{
    if (i.property == value)
    {
         foreach(var j in list.SubList)
         {
              if (j.other == something)
              {
                  results.push(j);
              }
         }
    }
}
```

could be:

```
var results = list.Where(i => i == value)
                  .SelectMany(i => i.SubList)
                  .Where(j => j.other == something)
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat contrived example.

Suppose you were given a list of strings and your task was to find and return all the control characters found in those strings in a `HashSet<>`.

```
var listOStrings = new List<string> { ... };
var result = new HashSet<char>();
```

You might do something like this:

```
foreach (var str in listOStrings)
{
    foreach (var c in str)
    {
        if (Char.IsControl(c))
        {
            result.Add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Or using LINQ:

```
result = new HashSet<char>(
    listOStrings
        .SelectMany(str => str.Where(Char.IsControl)));
```

Comment: Actually, I see a lot of people use Linq like this, so maybe it's not that contrived after all.

Answer (score 1):

The most useful examples are when you can use the built in methods in LINQ, like `All` and `Any`. Like this:

```
bool hasCats = listOfAnimals.Any(animal => animal.Type == "Cat");
```

Write that with a for loop with if and break and a bool check variable, I guess that would be at least five lines of code to do the same. Hmm, lets see:

```
bool hasCats = false;
foreach(Animal animal in listOfAnimals)
{
    if (animal.Type == "Cat")
    {
        hasCats = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

ooops, 9 lines. And you need to read at least three carefully of them to know what the code does.

Well, more of the same. Assuming the mammals have a real type hierarchy.

```
IEnumerable<Cat> allCats = listOfAnimals.OfType<Cat>();
```

This returns all animals that can be casted into a `Cat` and returns them, casted and ready to use. Written with loops:

```
List<Cat> allCats = new List<Cat>();
foreach(var animal in listOfAnimals)
{
    var cat = animal as Cat;
    if (cat != null)
    {
        allCats.Add(cat);
    }
}
```

To be honest you should break that out to a separate method and use `yield return cat;` to get the same lazy behaviour as the LINQ version.

But I prefer the query syntax. It is nice and fluent to read with very little noice.

```
var cats = 
    from cat in listOfCats
    where cat.Age > 5
    where cat.Color == "White"
    select cat;
```

Written with plain loops

```
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();
foreach(Cat cat in listOfCats)
{
    if (cat.Age > 5)
    {
        if (cat.Color == "White")
        {
            cats.Add(cat);
        }
    }
}
```

again a separate method with `yield return` would be required to get the same lazy evaluation behavior.

Comment: Thanks, Albin. Your answer is missing the "before" part, which is what I asked for initially.

Comment: @Skywise, I thought the before parts would be trivial to write, but I added them.