# Breaking out of a method in a loop

Tags: java, methods, if-statement, while-loop, break

I have a method with a break statement in its if statement. The method is in a while loop. Will it break out of the while loop if I use break within the method's if statement or do I have to use [nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324831/breaking-out-of-a-nested-loop)?

```
public int x=0;public int y=0;
public boolean endCondition = true;
public void someMethod()
{
  if(x!=y) {//do something}
  else break;
} 
while(endCondition==true)
{ 
  this.someMethod();
}
System.out.println("Bloke");
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a proxy JVM. Simply trying your code would answer your question.

Comment: Please try to format your code properly, it's hard to follow loops and methods otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `break` without a loop or a `switch` . You need to use `return`. But it seems a endless method calling which would cause **StackOverflow** exception.

Answer (score 0):

To break out from a function you have to use `return`. `break` will break you out from only the inner loop inside which you are calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to return a boolean value from the method, which you can then use to decide whether to break the loop.

It's not important in this simple example, but it's usually a good idea to label your loops when using `break`, so it's clear what you are breaking out of, especially when using nested loops. See the label `FOO` below.

```
public boolean someMethod()
{
  if(x!=y) 
  {
    //do something
    return false;
  }
  return true; // break
} 

FOO:while(true)
{ 
  if(someMethod()) break FOO;
}
```