# How to go to the outer for-loop

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Breaking out of a nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324831/breaking-out-of-a-nested-loop)

I have two for loops like this:

```
for (...)
{
   // some code

   for (...)
   {
       if (something)
       {
            // go to the outer for loop   <<<<<< 
       }
   }

   // some more code here 
}
```

If I use `continue` it will go to the inner loop. I want it to go to the outer one.
How can I do that?

Comment: Not a dupe, he doesn't want to break the outer loop, it's the inner one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx). As the documentation says:

> The break statement terminates the closest enclosing loop or switch statement in which it appears. Control is passed to the statement that follows the terminated statement, if any.

So your code should look like this:

```
Outer For-Loop
{
   ...// some code
   Inner For-Loop
   {
       if( something  = true )
       {
            break;//breaks out of inner loop
       }
   }

   // some more code here 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

did you mean you want ["break"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx)???

Answer (score 3):

Using break instead of continue?

Answer (score 1):

this is another way to do it

> one: for( ){
>
> ```
>    for( ){
>
>         if(  ){
>
>           continue one
>        }  
>    }
> ```
>
> }

use the tag "name:" I used one:

when the condition is met then the code "continue one" will jump to the first for

Comment: is java. just remove the semicolons. that way would be groovy actually.

Comment: Well, neither Java or Groovy are C#. Note that the question is tagged C#. Which means that is the language that the question concerns.