# Possible to use break for outer loop?

Tags: c#, java

If I use `break` like the code below, then the loop within `row` won't iterate the rest if there is a match in the beginning, but what about the `col` loop?

Would it still iterate between 0 and 7? Is there a way to use `break` there as well?

```
for (int col = 0; col < 8; col ++)
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row ++)
        if (check something)
        {
            //Then do this;
            break;
        }
```

Comment: It won't break the outer loop, you would need to include a similar check there - maybe set a bool in the inner break.

Comment: Yes, it would continue to loop the outer loop. The way to break this is called `goto`.

Comment: It will break out the inner loop only, set some bool after "Then do this" and check after your inner loop.

Comment: Set col to 8 would work

Comment: @Sayse: unless he changes the limit of the loop ;)

Comment: Ah, breaking out of multiple loops.. the ultimate question. It seems so obvious but I wish there was some better language support rather than using a sentinel boolean. E.g. something like break(2) which breaks out twice. I mean, how hard can it be.

Comment: @Thomas It's as simple as a `goto`, although not recommended, as it makes reading the code that much harder.

Comment: @Nolonar Yeah, I knew about the goto but it is kind of a hack, and as you said, it makes the code difficult to follow.

Comment: @Thomas there are languages, like php, that support that syntax and semantics.

Comment: Unless you really have to do it for some mysterious reason (and that is usually veeeeeeeeery rare) AVOID breaks and especially goto's. That's the first sign that something is really wrong with your code logic.

Comment: @nsn I think that's just cargo-cult dogmatism. `break outerLoop` and `goto outside` are both well-known idioms that can immediately be understood.

Comment: c# case already answered some years before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/324831/1178314). And there are answers stating about java case there too.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

One option is to use a condition flag. You could then *either* break in the outer loop as well, or just use it as an extra condition within the `for` loops:

```cs
bool keepGoing = true;

for (int col = 0; col < 8 && keepGoing; col++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 8 && keepGoing; row++)
    {
        if (something)
        {
             // Do whatever
             keepGoing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In Java, you can specify a label to break to though. (I didn't see that this question was tagged Java as well as C#.)

```java
outerLoop:
for (...)
{
    for (...)
    {
        if (...)
        {
            break outerLoop;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, in C#, you *could* use a label and `goto`:

```cs
for (...)
{
    for (...)
    {
        if (...)
        {
            goto endOfLoop;
        }
    }
}
endOfLoop:
// Other code
```

I'd *really* recommend that you don't take either of these approaches though.

In both languages, it would usually be best to simply turn both loops into a single method - then you can just return from the method:

```cs
public void doSomethingToFirstOccurrence()
{
    for (...)
    {
        for (...)
        {
            if (...)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Today I'm  using Java. Can I use col < 8 && keepGoing; in Java also?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: Yes, but I'd still recommend using the "extract to method" approach.

Comment: OK, but which one used the "extract to method" or what do you mean?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: The bottom one - you move the two loops into a method on their own, which you can return from.

Comment: Aha! OK I got it, so it return from the method and leave both loop immediately when the if statement is achieved?

Comment: @3D-kreativ Yes, `return` exits the current method instantly. Except if you have a `finally` block, in which case the content of the `finally` block will be executed **before** exiting the current method, which is meant for closing open connections or  disposing of objects or the likes.

Comment: @3D-kreativ I just noticed my previous comment might not have been very clear: In order for the `finally` block to be executed, the `return` statement has to be called from within a `try` block that is linked with a `finally` block: `try { return; } finally { /* will always be executed when previous 'try' has finished, even when 'return' was called, or exception was thrown */ }`. Aside from the aforementioned `try-finally`, return will **always** exit the current method instantly.

Comment: In C# you can't break with a label, but you can break out using `goto` to a label right after the loop.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have more repulsion to the `goto endOfLoop` than `break outerLoop`? The `goto` actually looks a little bit more straightforward to me in this case. Is there any disadvantage to the `goto` here other than that there's a big stigma about it?

Comment: @PeterOlson: Oh I have a revulsion to both. In both cases I think it hurts readability, and I'd much rather refactor it away into a separate method. I can't remember the last time I used `goto` except when reproducing the async generated code, and I can't remember using a labelled `break` in Java either.

Comment: Right, I would definitely agree that refactoring into a separate method is superior to either approach, I just thought it was odd that you didn't really warn against using `break`, but you did so somewhat emphatically for `goto`.

Comment: @PeterOlson: Right - edited to make it clearer that I don't like either of them :)

Comment: I want to weigh in here because it really needs to be said. goto isn't nice to read. You should avoid it where possible. However, in C#, breaking nested loops is one of two places where goto is actually the 'best way'. It is concise and quick. The other 'best use' is case statement fall-though, where it is required.

Comment: @Gusdor: Better than refactoring to a method, in your view?

Comment: @JonSkeet i would say it depends on the length of the inner loop code. There will come a point where it is a stylistic choice focussed on legibility - no one wants huge methods. Personally, I try to avoid overly specific private methods as I feel it causes bloat.

Comment: @Gusdor: You'd have to define "bloat" for me to agree or not, to be honest. But I can't remember the last time I regretted extracting a nested loop out of a method and giving it a really good name instead - I find it increases readability significantly. Mind you, often nested loops can be converted into LINQ queries instead...

Comment: In my world, bloat is extra syntax (therefore, lines) that you dont need. In this case it would be the method declaration for (at its smallest) a 4 line 'if-else'. Next time I hit some nested loops I shall give your  method a shot sir.

Comment: @Gusdor: Readability is about much more than just line count. Often you can find a relatively long method can be broken into several short methods each of which tackles a single aspect, and one "coordinator" method which just calls each method in turn. While the code ends up being longer, it can be *much* quicker to read that way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30735/discussion-between-gusdor-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @Jon, by 'coordinator' method I believe you mean the '[Composed Method](http://c2.com/ppr/wiki/WikiPagesAboutRefactoring/ComposedMethod.html)'. Right?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it is possible by using a `break` label:

```
package others;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        outer: for(int col = 0; col < 8; col ++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < 8; row ++)
            {
                if (col == 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("hi");
                    break outer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can put logic like this:

```
boolean condition = false;

for (int col = 0; col < 8; col ++)
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row ++)
        if (check something) {
            // Then do this:
            condition = true; // Break condition for outer loop
            break;
        }
     }
     if (condition)
         break;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't exit the col loop.

Instead, you can wrap all in a function and use `return;` to exit immediately from the loop

```
private Xy Loop( /* Parameters */)
    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col ++)
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row ++)
            if (check something) {
                // Then do this;
                return something; //Or just return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more useful in a language like C where you can't break multiple loops. You can use goto, but generally people say goto is a no-no.

Answer (score 3):

`break` only breaks the loop that is directly around it. You could use a flag to control the outer loop:

```
boolean continueOuterLoop = true;

for(int col = 0; continueOuterLoop && col < 8; col ++) {
    for(int row = 0; row < 8; row ++) {
        if(check something) {
            //Then do this;
            continueOuterLoop = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be my preferred way (but you still need to break the inner loop).

Answer (score 3):

```
nameHere:
for (yourForLoop) {
    for (anotherLoop) {
        if(condition) {
            break nameHere;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One more alternative to the other answers is to set your counters to the maximum, to stop the loops.

```
for (int col = 0; col < 8; col ++)
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row ++)
        if (check something)
        {
            // Use the col and row here.

            // Now we go for a totally break of all loops.
            // To stop the loops you can set that to the maximum
            // of your loop test.
            row = 8;
            col = 8;
        }
```

The advantage to that trick is that you do not add any additional checking code to the full loop and that makes it a lot faster.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you can use a `break label`.

```java
outer: 
for (int col = 0; col < 8; col ++)
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row ++)
        if (check something)
        {
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

And, since nobody else has mentioned it yet, in C#, you can use `goto label`.

```cs
for (int col = 0; col < 8; col ++)
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row ++)
        if (check something)
        {
            goto outside;
        }
    }
}
outside:
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a tag or a label, like "outerLoop". This works in Java:

```java
outerLoop:
    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col ++)
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row ++)
            if (check something)
            {
                //Then do this;
                break outerLoop;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. One way is to set the max value of the variable in the outer loop.

```
int maxcol = 8;
for (int col = 0; col < maxcol; col++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
    {
        if (check something)
        {
            Then do this;

            // cause the outer loop to break:
            col = maxcol;
            // break the inner loop
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the col = 8 and then break to inner loop.

Comment: Manipulating the for loop counters like this is not recommended. The counter should represent the number of iterations that have passed so if you set it to 8 when you haven't don't 8 iterations is a lie. You are also using the variable for more than one purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```java
Loop1: 
for (int col = 0; col < 8; col ++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row ++)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            break Loop1;
        }
    }
}
```

This could do what you need.

Answer (score -1):

We could use the concept of a flag variable:

```java
flag = 1;
for (int col = 0; col < 8; col ++)
{
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row ++)
        {
            if (flag == 1)
            {
                if (check something)
                {
                    //Then do this;
                    flag = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```