# C# How to I escape 2 lines of loops

Tags: c#, loops

This is my code:

```
while(true){
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        StringArray[x] = new string();
        if(isDead){
            break; //break out of while loop also
        }
    }
}
```

How should i do this please, sorry if my english is good,i still learning.

Comment: you can make `x = 2` instead of `0` and you should provide more info on when to break the loop??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breaking out of a nested loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324831/breaking-out-of-a-nested-loop)

Comment: Could you please submit all the code, this isnt enough to fully understand whats going on.

Comment: It is likely that this is a duplicate, I think @Houseman is right.

Comment: So I am not the only one who doesnt understand whats going on

Comment: you can always resort to the much maligned `goto` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a bool for example:

```
bool leaveLoop;
```

And if isDead is true then set leaveLoop to true, in the while loop then check if the leaveLoop is true to break from it.

Answer (score 3):

Change your while loop to a variable, then set that variable to false (your `isDead` variable for instance)

```
while(!isDead){
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        StringArray[x] = new string();
        if(isDead){
            break; //break out of while loop also
        }
    }
}
```

That way, your `break` will get you out of the `for` loop, then having the `isDead` set to true will stop the `while` loop executing.

Answer (score 1):

create a function inline, and call it. use return from within the lambda.

```
var mt = () => {
    while(true){
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
            StringArray[x] = new string();
            if(isDead){
               return
            }
        }
    }    
}
mt();
```

Answer (score 1):

So as I understand you wanted to break 2 Loops on one condition. You can do the following

```
bool DirtyBool = true;
while(DirtyBool)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        StringArray[x] = new string();
        if(isDead)
        {
            DirtyBool = false;
            break; //break out of while loop also
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
bool bKeepRunning = true;
while(bKeepRunning){
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
       StringArray[x] = new string();
       if(isDead){
         bKeepRunning = false;
         break; 
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite approach to this sort of situation is to move the code into a separate routine and simply return from it when I need to break.  Two loops is as much complexity as I like to include in a single routine anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `goto`:

```
    while(true){
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
            StringArray[x] = new string();
            if(isDead){
                goto EndOfWhile; //break out of while loop also
            }
        }
    }
EndOfWhile: (continue your code here)
```