# Interview Quest.: What can't be done in a nested loop in C#

Tags: c#, nested-loops

I have just been asked this question in an interview: "What can't be done in a nested loop in C#?" and I was stumped!

Is there a correct answer to this question? Or is it meant to stump people?

Comment: depends on context as what you are trying to do?

Comment: @SomeUser could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am almost certain that the interviewer was talking about breaking out of the *outer* loop without using `goto` statement.

This is, indeed, a problem that has been successfully solved in other similar languages, such as [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/886955/335858).

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/324831/335858) provides more information on the problem.

Comment: could you please elaborate!?

Comment: this was my thought.  But with it being possible with a `goto`, it's a very poor question.

Comment: You can use return, if this is the case.

Comment: @viveknuna Breaking out the loop is not the same as ending method execution.

Comment: throw can also be used :)

Comment: @Botonomous `break` would only break out of the inner loop. You'd have to set a flag or something, to indicate that the outer loop should break, and then have the code in the outer loop check that flag and break if it's set.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot guess what was expected answer but one comes to mind. It is mentioned in [C# specs chapter 3.7 Scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx)

> within a nested block it is not possible to declare a local variable with the same name as a local variable in an enclosing block

Comment: That's perfectly fair. However, this isn't unique to blocks inside nested loops: blocks inside top-level loops, inside `if`s, etc. all fall under this restriction.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I fully agree with you. extereme examples `{ { int t = 0; } { int t = 1; } }` - allowed, `{ int x = 0; { int x = 0; } }` - doesn't compile