# Is any break inside an if in a switch enough to break out of the switch in C#?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
switch (App.co)
{
    case CO.Random:
        var looking = true;
        while (looking)
        {
            // 
            if (xxx)
            {
                looking = false;
            }
        }
        break;

    case CO.FirstToLast:
```

What I would like to do is to replace it with this:

```
switch (App.co)
{
    case CO.Random:

        while (true)
        {
            // 
            if (xxx)
            {
                break
            }
        }
        break;

    case CO.FirstToLast:
```

I am not sure of the way the break is handled and would like to have some confirmation if it's exactly the same to replace the looking flag with a break here

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens..?

Comment: It seems to me you are trying to [break from nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/324831/1997232).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `break` is contextual to where it's used. In your first example the `case` is broken out of. In the second example, the `while` loop would be broken out of. The same holds true for a `for` nested in a `switch`.

This also applies to `for`, `while`, `switch`, etc. blocks - the closest relevant block is exited and execution continues on the next line after that block.

Answer (score 1):

As per the MSDN:

> The [break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break) statement terminates the closest enclosing loop or
>   switch statement in which it appears. Control is passed to the
>   statement that follows the terminated statement, if any